# Can't compile Java with Sublime Text 2, Ubuntu 12.04 64

Tags: java, ubuntu, sublimetext2

I am trying to compile and run .java files with [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 2, on my Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) 64-bit system and I get some errors.

My `java -version output`:

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

And here is my `JavaC.sublime-build` file contents:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","java", "$file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "shell": true
}
```

And finally my `.java` file, `bob.java`

```
public class bob{
    public static void main(){
        System.out.println("Sublime Text 2!");
    }
}
```

[Here is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKNAM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
    "shell": true,
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a format change in how Sublime Text 2 handles the cmd tag. An alternative solution would be:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name"],
    "cmd": ["java", "$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Credits: [DevinClark / JavaCandR.sublime-build](https://gist.github.com/1633819)