# Sublime Text 2 - Out of the box Compiling and running Java programs

Tags: java, sublimetext2, javac

OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

**Sublime Text 2 is 2.0.1 for Linux 32-bit**

There is JAVA_HOME set up in my environment and JAVA_HOME/bin included in $PATH

```
  $ cat /etc/bash.bashrc
  export ENV_HOME="/media/work/Environment"
  export JAVA_HOME="$ENV_HOME/Java/jdk1.7.0_04"

  export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Isn't Java program compilation and running supported out-of-the-box without any manual configurations or modifications?

When I am trying to build my simple program Test.java

```
  class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Jignesh Gohel");
  }
  }
```

I am getting the following error in Sublime Text console:

```
  [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  [cmd:  [u'javac', u'/media/work/Java/Test.java']]
  [dir:  /media/work/Java]
  [path: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games]
  [Finished]
```

Following is the JavaC.sublime-build content:

```
  {
      "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
      "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
      "selector": "source.java"
  }
```

I found following links mentioning solution to my above query:

https://gist.github.com/jfcalvo/3789664
   http://www.compilr.org/compile-and-run-java-programs/1251/
   [Can't compile Java with Sublime Text 2, Ubuntu 12.04 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271147/cant-compile-java-with-sublime-text-2-ubuntu-12-04-64)

but they still require me to make modifications manually.

Thanks,

Jignesh

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you figured out how to fix this?

Comment: After facing the mentioned problem I stopped using it for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you would like to give it a try again for sublime text.

It is really an editor which is flexible for the programmers.

After digging into the problem that we both have,

you can revise your JavaC.sublime-build as the following.

```
{
  "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
  "shell": true,
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.java"
}
```

By doing this, pressing F7 should come up with something you expect.